# Как вытащить из функции Список?

Tags: python

в питоне новичок, не понимаю в чём проблема, есть функция, делаю return хочу вызвать функцию, но выводит пустой список, много чего пробовал, но заметил, что до return, если написать print(), то функция спокойно, но локально даёт информацию в функции, хочется вытащить список глобально.
Вот само чудо:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://pogoda.mail.ru/prognoz/komsomolsk-na-amure/'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36 OPR/87.0.4390.58 (Edition Yx GX 03)',
           'accept': '*/*'}

def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='information block js-city_one')

    pogoda = []

    for item in items:
        pogoda.append({
            'cels': item.find('div', class_='information__content__temperature').get_text(strip=True),
            'celsmb': item.find('div', class_='information__content__additional__item').get_text(strip = True).replace('ощущается как', ''),
            })
    return pogoda

def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print('Возникла ошибка!')
parse()
```

Comment: `print(get_content(html.text))` вы возвращаете список, но не принимаете его ни в какую переменную и не печатаете

Comment: В том то и дело я убрал все принты, а если сделать как Вы написали, то он просит html, который в функции

Comment: у меня не просит. я ваш вызов get_content заменил на свой с принтом, получил в консоль `[{'cels': '+22°', 'celsmb': '+22°C'}]`

Comment: А куда вы его поставили, если не секрет?

Comment: `if html.status_code == 200: print(get_content(html.text))`

Comment: Так это тоже в функции, мне бы это сделать как глобальную переменную, ну точнее вывод информации, список и в def get_content выводится, если просто написать print(pogoda)

Comment: `if html.status_code == 200:  return get_content(html.text)` и `mypogoda =  parse()` вы про это?

Comment: Да, да и ещё раз да, спасибо большое!)